# Insert new record into autonumbered table, and then use the autonumber in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm writing a stored procedure to insert data from a form into two tables.  One table has an autonumbered identity field.  I need to insert the data into that table, find the newly created autonumber, and use that number to insert data into another table.  So, to boil it down, I have a one-to-many link between the two tables and I need to make sure the identity field gets inserted.

Is this code the best way to do something like this, or am I missing something obvious?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Insert_CRT]
(
    @TRACKING_ID int,
    @CUST_NUM int,
    @TRACKING_ITEM_ID int,
    @STATEMENT_NUM nvarchar (200) = null,
    @AMOUNT numeric (15, 2),
    @BBL_ADJUSTED int = NULL,
    @PAID_VS_BILLED int = NULL,
    @ADJUSTMENT_TYPE int = NULL,
    @ENTERED_BY nvarchar (10) = NULL,
    @ENTERED_DATE date = NULL,
    @AA_STATUS int = NULL  
)

AS
BEGIN

-- Insert data into CRT_Main, where Tracking_ID is an autonumber field
      INSERT into tbl_CRT_Main
      (
--      TRACKING_ID
        CUST_NUM
        ,TRACKING_ITEM_ID
        ,STATEMENT_NUM
        ,AMOUNT
        )
      
        VALUES 
        (
--      @TRACKING_ID
        @CUST_NUM
        ,@TRACKING_ITEM_ID
        ,@STATEMENT_NUM
        ,@AMOUNT
        )

-- Find the newly generated autonumber, and use it in another table
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DECLARE @TrackID int;
        SELECT @TrackID = coalesce((select max(TRACKING_ID) from tbl_CRT_Main), 1)
    COMMIT

      INSERT into tbl_CRT_Admin_Adjustment
      (
        TRACKING_ID
        ,BBL_ADJUSTED
        ,PAID_VS_BILLED
        ,[ADJUSTMENT_TYPE]
        ,[ENTERED_BY]
        ,[ENTERED_DATE]
        ,AA_STATUS

        )
      
        VALUES 
        (
        @TrackID
        ,@BBL_ADJUSTED
        ,@PAID_VS_BILLED
        ,@ADJUSTMENT_TYPE
        ,@ENTERED_BY
        ,@ENTERED_DATE
        ,@AA_STATUS
        )

END
```

Comment: FYI, don't use `sp_` as a prefix for your object. It is reserved by Microsoft, for **S**pecial **P**rocedures. It's use comes with a performance cost *and* could result in your procedure simply not working on day after an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT @TrackID = coalesce((select max(TRACKING_ID) from tbl_CRT_Main), 1)
```

No, don't do this. This will get you the maximum value of `TRACKING_ID` yes, but that doesn't mean that's the value that was created for your `INSERT`. If multiple `INSERT` statements were being run by different connections then very likely you would get the *wrong* value.

Instead, use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to get the value:

```
SET @TrackID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Also, there is no need to wrap the above in an explicit transaction like you have with your `SELECT MAX()`. Instead, most likely, the *entire* batch in the procedure should be inside it's own explicit transaction, with a `TRY...CATCH` so that you can `ROLLBACK` the whole batch in the event of an error.

Comment: Personally wouldn't bother with a `try/catch/rollback` it can get very messy, and is difficult for beginners to write. Just `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` with a transaction should be enough

Comment: Maybe it's just me, @Charlieface , but I don't really see a `TRY...CATCH` as being messy or difficult to understand; even for people fairly new to the language. Unlike other operations, it works very similarly to programming language `try...catch` syntax, which people often have had some exposure to.

Comment: `try/catch/if trancount... rollback/select error_message...` just too much boiler plate for me, the only benefit I ever find is to implement server-side logging, which I rarely do. `XACT_ABORT` automatically rolls back everything anyway, what gain is there by doing `try/catch` also?

Comment: I often find I am `THROW`ing bespoke errors, @Charlieface , so I suppose that's why I find myself using it more.